# Right way to convert data.frame to a numeric matrix, when df also contains strings?

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, numeric

I have a data frame taken from a .csv-file which contains numeric and character values. I want to convert this data frame into a matrix. All containing information is numbers (the non-number-rows I deleted), so it should be possible to convert the data frame into a numeric matrix. However, I do get a character matrix.

I found the only way to solve this is to use `as.numeric` for each and every row, but this is quite time-consuming. I am quite sure there is a way to do this with some kind of `if(i in 1:n)`-form, but I cannot figure out how it might work. Or is the only way really to already start with numeric values, like proposed here([Making matrix numeric and name orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052828/making-matrix-numeric-and-name-orders))?

Probably this is a very easy thing for most of you :P

The matrix is a lot bigger, this is only the first few rows... Here's the code:

```
cbind(
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,1]),
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,2]),
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,3]),
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,4]),
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,5]),
as.numeric(SFI.Matrix[ ,6]))  

# to get something like this again:

Social.Assistance Danger.Poverty GINI S80S20 Low.Edu        Unemployment 
0.147             0.125          0.34    5.5   0.149        0.135 0.18683691
0.258             0.229          0.27    3.8   0.211        0.175 0.22329362
0.207             0.119          0.22    3.1   0.139        0.163 0.07170422
0.219             0.166          0.25    3.6   0.114        0.163 0.03638525
0.278             0.218          0.29    4.1   0.270        0.198 0.27407825
0.288             0.204          0.26    3.6   0.303        0.211 0.22372633
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Converting numerics-stored-as-strings back to numerics is trivial. Converting other strings to numerics is impossible (unless they're factors, in which case it's a terrible practice, statistically). As to factors, you didn't mention them, but converting factors to numeric is the only interesting part of this question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Edit 2:  See @flodel's answer.   Much better.

Try:

```
# assuming SFI is your data.frame
as.matrix(sapply(SFI, as.numeric))
```

Edit: 
or as @ CarlWitthoft suggested in the comments:

```
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(SFI)),nrow=nrow(SFI))
```

Comment: yes, SFI was the data.frame, and yes, it solved the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply `matrix(as.numeric(unlist(SFI)),nr=nrows(SFI))` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, due to doubt of how the coercion of `unlist` would affect the final result, but you might be right in that regardless of the intermediate coercion, the final coercion from `as.numeric` should produce the same results.  Answer updated

Answer (score 60):

```
data.matrix(SFI)
```

From `?data.matrix`:

```
Description:

 Return the matrix obtained by converting all the variables in a
 data frame to numeric mode and then binding them together as the
 columns of a matrix.  Factors and ordered factors are replaced by
 their internal codes.
```

Comment: this will interpret "123" as a factor and convert it to the related integer level.

Comment: @antonio. What you say is not true. If the data.frame contains characters, they are converted to numerics, try: `data.matrix(data.frame(x = "123", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`. It is only if the data.frame contains factors that they are represented by their internal value (as quoted above), try `data.matrix(data.frame(x = "123", stringsAsFactors = TRUE))`. So everything is behaving as I would expect and as documented.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you don't get straight a number out of string, unless you use `stringsAsFactors`  or `as.is`  for `read.csv`.

Comment: data.matrix(as.data.frame(SFI,stringsAsFactors = F) )

Comment: one more subtlety: if all values were integer (or can be interpreted as such), the end result is an integer matrix, not a numeric matrix (which e.g. cannot be clustered using `hopach`, and `as.numeric` looses the dimensions again ...). I think in this respect the documentation is unclear in that 'numeric mode' also includes integers.

And now that I think about it, it is weird that `as.numeric` always returns a double, that is not very consistent since in all other contexts, `numeric` means `integer-or-double` ...

Comment: converting a data.table which has factor column types to a matrix with data.matrix will result in an integer matrix, not numeric.

Comment: data.matrix() is slow compared to as.matrix()

Comment: @user3503711, OP mentions how his data converts to a *character* matrix, so `as.matrix` is not enough. It's the necessary conversion to numeric that slows things down.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an alternative way if the data frame just contains numbers.

```html
apply(as.matrix.noquote(SFI),2,as.numeric)
```

but the most reliable way of converting a data frame to a matrix is using `data.matrix()` function.

Comment: data.matrix didn't work but your solution worked :-)

Comment: This is the real answer. The other solutions all clobbered the data in some way for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by using the `read.table()` argument `colClasses` to specify the column type by making `colClasses=c(*column class types*)`. 
If there are 6 columns whose members you want as numeric, you need to repeat the character string `"numeric"` six times separated by commas, importing the data frame, and `as.matrix()` the data frame. 
P.S. looks like you have headers, so I put `header=T`.

```
as.matrix(read.table(SFI.matrix,header=T,
colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric"),
sep=","))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this, by
taking the original data frame without row names and adding them later

```
SFIo <- as.matrix(apply(SFI[,-1],2,as.numeric))
row.names(SFIo) <- SFI[,1]
```

Answer (score -2):

I manually filled NAs by exporting the CSV then editing it and reimporting, as below.

Perhaps one of you experts might explain why this procedure worked so well 
(the first file had columns with data of types `char`, `INT` and `num` (floating point numbers)), which all became `char` type after STEP 1; but at the end of STEP 3 R correctly recognized the datatype of each column).

```
# STEP 1:
MainOptionFile <- read.csv("XLUopt_XLUstk_v3.csv",
                            header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#... STEP 2:
TestFrame <- subset(MainOptionFile, str_locate(option_symbol,"120616P00034000") > 0)
write.csv(TestFrame, file = "TestFrame2.csv")
# ...
# STEP 3:
# I made various amendments to `TestFrame2.csv`, including replacing all missing data cells with appropriate numbers. I then read that amended data frame back into R as follows:    
XLU_34P_16Jun12 <- read.csv("TestFrame2_v2.csv",
                            header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

On arrival back in R, all columns had their correct measurement levels automatically recognized by R!

Comment: You replaced missing data with numbers?  How'd that analysis go?

Comment: The data missing were stock price quotes in two blocks of cells, Richard. So I manually supplied them.  I am guessing that what was key was the outputting of the file by R at Step 2, which must have facilitated R's correct interpretation of every column when the file was returned to it at Step 3. Anyway, it was a *big* file, so i was really happy to avoid having to describe data structures for individual columns.

Comment: @user3315638: exporting and reimporting was totally unnecessary, all you are doing is `sapply(df[,StringColsToChangeToNumeric], as.numeric)`

Comment: @RichardScriven: in real-world datasets (financial, weblog etc.), filling or imputing NAs is not only important but necessary (obviously, caveats apply). Having said that, this export-CSV-edit-reimport is unnecessary and error-prone and can be replaced with the one-liner above.