# How to create a data.frame with a matrix as a variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

My data frame has a first column of factors, and all the other columns are numeric.

```
       Origin spectrum_740.0 spectrum_741.0 spectrum_742.0   etc....
1     Warthog      0.6516295      0.6520196      0.6523843
2       Tiger      0.4184067      0.4183569      0.4183805
3 Sperm whale      0.9028763      0.9031688      0.9034069
```

I would like to convert the data frame into two variables, a vector (the first column) and a matrix (all the numeric columns), so that I can do calculations on the matrix, such as applying `msc` from the `pls` package. Basically, I want the data frame to be like the `gasoline` data set from `pls`, which has one variable as a numeric vector, and a second variable called NIR as a matrix with 401 columns.

Alternatively, if you have any suggestions for applying calculations to the numeric data while keeping the Origin column connected, that would work too, but all the examples I have seen use `gasoline` or similarly formatted data frames to do the calculations on the NIR matrix.

Thank you!

Comment: Turn the "Origin" column to rownames of a numeric matrix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right way to convert data.frame to a numeric matrix, when df also contains strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518428/right-way-to-convert-data-frame-to-a-numeric-matrix-when-df-also-contains-strin)

Answer (score 1):

```
M = as.matrix(df[,-1])
row.names(M) = df[,1]
M
            spectrum_740.0 spectrum_741.0 spectrum_742.0
Warthog          0.6516295      0.6520196      0.6523843
Tiger            0.4184067      0.4183569      0.4183805
Sperm_whale      0.9028763      0.9031688      0.9034069
```